# Spring data jpa: write query which will @ManyToOne object with filtered @ManyToOne list

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Let's say i have 2 domain objects:
User:

```
//Entity, Geter, Setter, equalsAndHashCode
class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Unique
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Orders> orders;
}
```

Oder:

```
class Order {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private User user;

  private OffsetDateTime startTime;
}
```

How tables look:

```
 -------         ----------
|  User |       |   Order  |
|-------|       |----------|
|  id   |       |    id    |
|-------|       |----------|
|  name |       |  user_id |
 -------        |----------| 
                |start_time|
                 ----------
```

I have User Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    

  @Query(to be done)
  Optional<User> findByUserNameWithOrdersAfter(@Param("userName") String userName,
                                               @Param("startTime") OffsetDateTime startTime);
  
}
```

In brief, i need to have an ability to get domain object User from the database with already filtered list of orders.

For example, db contain orders:

```
Order a startTime Monday for user Sam
Order b startTime Friday for user Sam
Order c startTime Friday for user Sam
```

My **findByUserNameWithOrdersAfter("Sam", OffsetDateTime.of("Thursday"))** should return me user *sam*, which has orders B and C.

I have tried to do select user by orders and join user, but if i don't have any orders i wouldn't have a chance to get user from database.

Thanks!

UPD: please, provide examples only with custom @Query. My logic is more complex )
UPD 2: If there is no orders for user, i expect to find user with empty oreders list

Answer (score 0):

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    

  @Query("""SELECT u from User u 
            LEFT JOIN FETCH u.orders o 
            WHERE u.name = :username AND 
            (u.orders IS EMPTY OR o.startTime > :startTime)""")

  Optional<User> findByUserNameWithOrdersAfter(@Param("userName") String userName,
                                               @Param("startTime") OffsetDateTime startTime);
  
}
```

You have to fetch user and its orders within one query. If you omit `fetch` clause, then `user.getOrders()` is lazily evaluated and another query is perfomed. The latter one knows nothing about `o.startTime > :startTime` condition and just retrieves all orders belonging to this user.

In this case, you get a user with orders according to filtering by `startTime` or user that has no orders at all.

Comment: In this case i will recieve Empty optional, if User has orders with startTime Monday, Tuesday. But if I wil try to find User with orders on Friday - I will get null

Comment: @smith77aim Why do you think you'll get `null`? If `User` is not found, then the method returns empty Optional

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not clear. Let's say i have User Sam and 2 orders with startTime Tuesday. If I will query user "Sam" where startTime > Monday, everything will be OK - i will get Sam with list of 2 Orders. But if I will query user "Sam" where order.startTime is > Friday I will recieve Empty Optional. But I would like to recieve Sam with empty list of the Orders in this case. So, if there is NO APPLICABLE RECORDS for WHERE clause, my qury will be failed (nothing will be found)